# I want to folders parsing only at one level, take folder name and use it to construct path don't want to go in all subdirectory recursively

Tags: c++, linux, directory, path, dirent.h

Following code I have implemented :
I want to search enlist 2 folder present under directory and search for ref .txt file and  build path .
Current code is working , But it's searching every subdirectory  present in 2 folder inside parent directory. It's delaying the process.

Eg: There are multiple folder/Sub directory present inside A and B both We don't want to traverse inside those .

folder structure is just for reference (but It's on linux)
**\A\ref.txt**

**\B\ref.txt**

I want to get A and B only ( 1 level directory parse, make path and read ref.txt)

```
void getDir(std::string directory)
{
    std::string dirToOpen = path + directory;
    DIR * dir = opendir(dirToOpen.c_str());
    path = dirToOpen + "/";
    if(NULL == dir)
        return;
    struct dirent * entity = readdir(dir);
    while(entity != NULL)
    {
        getEntity(entity);
        entity = readdir(dir);
    }
    path.resize(path.length() - 1 - directory.length());
    closedir(dir);
}

void getEntity(struct dirent* entity)
{
    if (NULL == entity)
        return;
    if(entity->d_type == DT_DIR)
    {
        if(entity->d_name[0] == '.')
        {
            return;
        }
        getDir(std::string(entity->d_name));
        return;
    }
    if(entity->d_type == DT_REG)
    {
        buildPath(std::string(entity->d_name));
        return;
    }
}

void buildPath(std::string file)
{
    if (file == std::string("ref.txt")) 
    {
        std::cout << "file found " <<  std::endl;
        str::string Path_1 = path + file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem (but might make it simpler to solve it?) I suggest you take a look at the C++ [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) namespace.

Comment: I have tried that  , My compiler (5.4)  is not supporting that .

Comment: Find all directories in the root directory (`C:/`), then for each directory do a second search to find `ref.txt`.

Comment: By the way, you mention the Windows `C` drive, and have tagged Linux. Which is correct, the Windows `C` drive, or the Linux tag (they are really mutually exclusive)?

Comment: If I comment    getDir(std::string(entity->d_name)); this , will it work?  It's on linux . Just for reference  , I have put folder str like that.